# How do you remove non-ASCII characters (AltCodes) from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, ascii

How can I remove non-ASCII characters (Altcodes) from a string such as:
→
←
█
◄
►
∙

Comment: `yourStringVariable.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7E]", "");`.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as AltCode? `ö`? `€`? Emojis? Do you want to only keep ASCII characters?

Comment: Oh...just to be clear, all characters in ASCII have an ALT Code number (A is 065, B is 066, etc).

Comment: I only want to keep ASCII Characters

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, by "AltCode", you're referring to any non-ASCII character.

One solution to this problem would be use the method [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).  This method replaces all instances of the given [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) with a given replacement string.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Java has the "\p{ASCII}" pattern which match only ASCII characters.  This can be negated using "[^…]" syntax to match any non-ASCII characters instead.  The matched characters can then be replaced with the empty string, effectively removing them from the resulting string.

```java
String s = "A→←B█◄C►";
String stripped = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println(stripped); // Prints "ABC"
```

The full list of valid regex pattern characters is documented in the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Note: If you are going to be calling this pattern multiple times within a run, it will be more efficient to use a compiled `Pattern` directly, rather than `String.replaceAll`.  This way the pattern is compiled only once and reused, rather than each time `replaceAll` is called:

```java
public class AsciiStripper {
    private static final Pattern NON_ASCII_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{ASCII}]");
    
    public String stripAscii(String s) {
        return NON_ASCII_PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
    }
}
```